# Place rate limit exceeded after enable billing, what is wrong?

Tags: android, google-places-api

I googled but did not find my solution. I'm still getting place rate limit exceeded error after enable billing. Please help me how to solve this issue, my App is live on Play Store.

Comment: It will take some some. Wait for it.

Comment: how much? its been 15 Hours.

Comment: Rate limit means queries per second (QPS). Google Maps API web services have 50 QPS limit. How many QPS are you sending? Are you stay within 50 QPS?